# WebResult vs RequestWrapper Annotations with Polymophism

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, jaxb2

I have a class such as the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://foo.com/model", name = "Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://foo.com/model", name = "Person"
public abstract Person {
}
```

And two classes that inherit from that:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://foo.com/model", name = "ShortPerson")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://foo.com/model", name = "ShortPerson"
public ShortPerson extends Person {
}

@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://foo.com/model", name = "TallPerson")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://foo.com/model", name = "TallPerson"
public TallPerson extends Person {
}
```

Then I have an SEI as such:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://foo.com/services")
public interface PersonService {
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getPersonById", className = "com.foo.services.personService.GetPersonById", targetNamespace = "http://foo.com/services")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getPersonByIdResponse", className = "com.foo.services.personService.GetPersonByUidResponse", targetNamespace = "http://foo.com/services")
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "http://foo.com/model", name = "Person")
    Person getPersonById(
        @WebParam(targetNamespace = "http://foo.com/services", name = "PersonId") Long personId);

}
```

And my response wrapper class looks as such:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "getPersonByIdResponse", namespace = "http://foo.com/services")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getPersonByIdResponse", namespace = "http://foo.com/services", propOrder = { "person" })
public class GetPersonByIdResponse {

   @XmlElementRefs( {
        @XmlElementRef(name = "TallPerson", type = TallPerson.class, namespace = "http://foo.com/model"),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "SmallPerson", type = SmallPerson.class, namespace = "http://foo.com/model")

   })
   private Person person;

   public Person getPerson() {
      return person;
   }

   public void setPerson(Person person) {
      this.person = person;
   }
```

}

So the issue here is that if I test the ResponseWrapper via JAXB directly and populate a TallPerson object, I correctly marshal that object into the XML that is specific to TallPerson (and the same works for SmallPerson).

The problem is when I deploy this in a war and service enable it, when a result is returned for TallPerson, I receive nothing from the web service call except an empty message.  In fact, I don't even receive the response wrapper root XML element of <getPersonByIdResponse>.

So my issue is if I have a polymorphic request or response object (in this case a response object), how does the WebResult name/targetnamespace effect the params within the ResponseWrapper.  Because in my case I am utilizing the XmlElementRefs to correctly marshal my base object Person into either TallPerson or SmallPerson, but how does this relate to the namespace/name of the parent class Person on the WebResult?  I am not sure if a conflict is causing the XML response to not get produced.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever solve this problem ?

I see similar problem in my webservice : 
I have a class named Flowers
and 3 classes that inherit from it, Roses, Tulips, SunFlowers

for some reason, when i send resposne of Roses and Tulips, the response isnt blank, but when i send SunFlowers, the response is blank. If you solved it, tell me please

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your clases will be loded to JAXB context by annotating service with XmlSeeAlso:

```
@WebService
@XmlSeeAlso({TallPerson.class,SmallPerson.class})
public interface PersonService {
    @WebResult(name = "Person")
    Person getPersonById(
        @WebParam(name = "PersonId") Long personId);

    }
```

And you don't need to play with wrappers. JAX-WS will handle this, also it will generate the correct WSDL.